# Discrete math on Paths and Connectivity

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Can someone describe the following question for me?
a) Describe a 5-regular simple graph with 12 vertices which is not connected. b) Let G be a 6-regular graph with 12 vertices. For any pair of different vertices x,y in G explain why there must always be a path from x to y whose length is 1 or 2.

Comment: Hint.  Start by drawing a $5$-regular simple graph with $6$ vertices.

Comment: Can you explain more please. because I don't understand how would you get the length form x to y

Comment: See the answer by @Nicholas.

Answer (score 1):

For the first, consider the hint by David: can you think of a $5$-regular simple graph on $6$ vertices?  If so, then two copies of that graph (with distinct vertex sets) will do it!

For the second: suppose that there is no path of length $1$ between two vertices $v$ and $w$, so that we must show that there is a path of length $2$. This is equivalent to saying that there must be some vertex $u$, distinct from $v$ and $w$, such that both $v$ and $w$ are adjacent to $u$.  Is it possible for the six neighbors each for $v$ and $w$, chosen from the $10$ vertices distinct from $v$ and $w$, to be disjoint?

Comment: I guess would be that they can't be disjoint

Comment: can you just give me the answer to part b) please? I appreciate it

Comment: @ali That's not how this site works. If you have further questions, show us where you are getting stuck and I may try to help you along.

Comment: @ali And to address your first comment: that's absolutely right.  How can you justify it?  (There's a two-word answer to this question!)

Answer (score 0):

For part b, since the graph is 6-regular, the diameter is bounded above by $log_{6}(12)$. In general, for a k-regular graph, the floor of $log_{k}(V)$ gives you the diameter.

Answer (score 0):

For part 2. Start at any vertex. Then you have 6 vertices distance 1. So you have 5 other vertices.  Pick any one of these vertices.  It is connected to 6 other vertices. So it must be connected to a distance 1 vertex as there are only 4 other non distance 1 vertices.  But if a vertex is connected to a distance 1 vertex it has distance 2.